# jQuery transitions: on load and after for each click, an addClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Well, let me try to explain my gol:
I did a small project (Random Quote Machine from ferecodecamp.com), and it is quite functional. But I want to make it like an slide show (Power Point) with transitions.

See what I have for now [Random Quote Machine project](https://samu101108.github.io/Intermediate_FrontEnd_Development_projects/Random%20Quote%20Machine/index.html#)

1. The page should load the quote making a transition from zero opacity to total.
   2 .When I click button generate, it should change the quote and again, it should be a quote thate comes from 0 opacity to 1.

The CSS could be something like:

```css
span, i, footer{
  opacity: 0;
}
.transitions {
  transition-duration: 1s;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

span, i, footer goes from 0 to 1 on opacity with a transition-duration of 1 second.

I tried some jQuery but nothing had gone well the way I want

```html
    <script type="text/javascript">
//for page load
        $(".quote").load(function(){
          $(".quote").addClass("transitions");
        });

//for new quote generated
        $(".button").click(function() {
            $(".quote").fadeOut("slow", function() {
                $(this).addClass("quote");
            });
            $(".quote").fadeIn("slow", function() {
                $(this).addClass("quote");
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Fist part doesn't work at all. The .load event has never worked and .ready just works with a .click event.

Second part, partialy works, but it first desapears and after apears. I want to be desapeared (0 opacity) to total apear...

I've been trying for two long days and nothing is going realy well. I would be really glad in read some suggestions.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
// equivalent to $(document).ready(function()
$(function() {

  // define an array of elements to fade
  var elements = [$('#quote'), $('#author')];

  fade(); // call a custom function defined below which will execute on page load

  // on .button click, call the same function
  $('.button').click(fade);

  function fade() {
    // for each element in elements (defined above), execute jQuery's hide() method and then fadeIn()

    $.each(elements, function(index, element) {
      element.hide().fadeIn();
    });
  }
});
```

If you paste this in the console within your [project](https://samu101108.github.io/Intermediate_FrontEnd_Development_projects/Random%20Quote%20Machine/index.html#), it works nicely.

Comment: It works great too! But for me looks a bit more complex.

Comment: I'll add comments to help explain.

Comment: I've updated with comments.  Please ask questions if you don't understand something.  Congrats on starting with freecodecamp!

Comment: The benefit of doing it this way instead of Villa7_'s way, is because all functionality is defined in one place.  If you want to change this functionality, you need to only update the `fade` function.  If you need to add another element as part of the `quote` component, for example, a Title, you only need to add that element the array of `elements`.

Comment: The idea of the array is really nice. Thanks for the comments, now it is even better!

Answer (score 2):

*note*: [`$.load()`](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/) was deprecated in jQuery version 1.8.

This should be what you wanted:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".quote").fadeIn(1000);
});

$(".button").click(function() {
    $(".quote").fadeOut(1000, function() {
        // change the quote here
        $(".quote").fadeIn(1000);
    });
});
```

```css
.quote {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button">new</button>

<div class="quote">quote</div>
```

Comment: Almost...
I really need to study more...I guess I would never know about deprecated .load event....

But in fact this is the perfect solution! Unique thing to change is  fadeOut to zero and it become what I intended since the begin! Great!